# MUI 5 TextField placeholder text color change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the placeholder text color and text color to green in my MUI TextFeild component

[image]

In the documentation, it is not clearly mentioned, But I tried this, and seems not working

```
<TextField
        multiline
        rows={3}
        id="outlined-basic"
        placeholder="My placeholder"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{
          "& .MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            color: "green"
          },
          "& .MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root ::placeholder": {
            color: "green"
          }
        }}
      />
```

How can I fix this?
This is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tdd-lqsy7m)

Answer (score 1):

With latest MUI v5, just use the below code:

```
  <Textfield sx={{
           input: {
     "&::placeholder": {
          opacity: 1
        }}
    }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

How I usually check if my selector is correct:

1. Copy this: `& .MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root`
2. Open inspect element
3. press `ctrl + f` in inspect elements panel to search
4. then paste it

And then You will find out that your selector is not correct. You missed the class selector `.` before `MuiOutlinedInput-root` at this one: `& .MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root`

Also class `MuiOutlinedInput-root` is not in the children, it is in the same element

The correct one is : `& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiOutlinedInput-root ::placeholder`

You can make it simpler like this: `& input::placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

Your classnames are incorrct

```js
"& .MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root ::placeholder"
// instead of 
"& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiOutlinedInput-root ::placeholder"
```

For the outline you can use `"& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline"`

```js
sx={{
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
    borderColor: "blue"
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-root.MuiOutlinedInput-root ::placeholder": {
    color: "blue"
  }
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the sx function, and reach the text area like this:

```
sx={{
      '& > div > textarea':{
        color: "background.default",
      },
    }}
```

That worked for me, hope it helps.